# How to put the dates in chronological order in python CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, data-processing

So I am working on processing some data and after running my file, everything is fine except that the date are not in order. I used the code below to try putting them in order but didnt work. by the way 'updated_at' is the column I am trying to put in chronological

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["updated_at"], ascending=True)
```

Please let me know how I can make this work. I have attached a picture to for better understanding of my question.

["updated_at" column pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYEqp.png)

Comment: It seems like the values in the column `"updated_at"` are strings

Comment: what do the dates look like [and type] once loaded into a dataframe? i suspect the excel format maybe at fault here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are missing a bit of the context, but it could be that the column "updated_at" is not a datetime column, but a simple string, since it looks to me it is sorted alfabetically. Check with `df["updated_at"].dtype` and if it's not a datetime type (it will probably be of type "object") then do

```
df["update_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["update_at"])
```